# A double-space in a comment removes the space immediately before the next link (Safari only)

Tags: support, comments, safari, whitespace

When I enter `a b y [z](https://duckduckgo.com)` and `a  b y [z](https://duckduckgo.com)` as comments, the two comments immediately below this post appear.

Here is a screenshot from Safari 7 on my Mac OS 10.9, in which it removed the space between the `y` and the `z` link.

> [image]

(In fact, I now notice that it also removed the hypen that usually separates user-name and time.)

Comment: a b y [z](https://duckduckgo.com)

Comment: a  b y [z](https://duckduckgo.com)

Comment: @JonK - this is just browser rendering. The whitespace is collapsed when viewed. See the source of the second comment - it has 2 spaces.

Comment: @Oded: When I look at the source of the second comment, I see _4_ spaces - two between `a` and `b`, one between `b` and `y`, and one between `y` and the `z` link.

Comment: @RickyDemer - um. Exactly like you posted them then. Your whole post was about the double space, no?

Comment: I posted a screen shot of the two comments in my answer. If this is different from what you see, please clarify - a screen shot would be best, as well as browser and OS details.

Comment: @Oded Fair enough - I don't really work with HTML much so that's my new thing learned for the day - at least I got the status-bydesign part (sort of) right!

Comment: That can only be explained as a bug in how Safari renders things. Nothing Stack Exchange could do about that one. Your browser is blatantly rendering things incorrectly.

Comment: Is it Safari 7 or 7.1? From what I can tell, the issue is specific to the browser, not much we can do if it doesn't render properly.

Comment: @Oded: It's 7.0.6.  Also, how did you upload my screenshot to i.stack.imgur.com?

Comment: We have an image upload built into the editor. I gave it the link to the actual image you uploaded and it did the rest. Did you try upgrading Safari to 7.1?

Comment: Oh.  I haven't tried upgrading yet.

Comment: a  a  [a](http://example.com)

Comment: +1, Same problem in Safari 7.1

Comment: Repro'd in Safari 8.0

Comment: Well, looks like a Safari-only issue. @Oded don't you have such a browser to test stuff on? :)

Comment: @Sha - I operate in an Apple free world ;) - will have others look at this.

Answer (score 7):

To clarify what I see:

> [image: two first comments from the question]

That's what browsers do when displaying whitespace. They collapse whitespace.

If you look at the HTML source for both comments, you will find that the spaces have been preserved.

First comment:

> [image: one space]

Second comment:

> [image: two spaces]

---

Now, looking at your screenshot, it is apparent that your browser is rendering incorrectly - why that is, I don't know. It could be something specific to your machine (or even just for now - if you reboot it might go), it could be something that is happening to everyone using the same OS/Browser versions.